# Is it bad practice in Laravel to specify where() and find() in one query?

Tags: php, laravel

In controller, which shows simple users

```
User::where('is_admin', false)->find($id);
```

In controller, which shows admins

```
User::where('is_admin', true)->find($id);
```

Of course, to add more magic we can do

```
public function scopeAdmins($query)
{
    return $query->where('is_admin', true);
}
```

And use

```
User::admins()->find($id);
```

But it is just syntactic sugar

Comment: There is no reason to avoid that. It's much more clear than User::where('is_admin', false)->where('id', $id)->first() which is the only one alternative that makes sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue with how you have it. Both the scope or the raw where clause would work. The scope is mostly syntactic sugar. The nice thing about scopes it is puts all admin constraints in one location so if you change how users are flagged as admin you only have to change it in one place.

You could potentially make the scope a little more generic like this:

```
public function scopeAdmins($query, $isAdmin = true)
{
    return $query->where('is_admin', $isAdmin);
}
```

Then get admins like

```
User::admins()->find($id); // or more explicitly User::admins(true)->find($id);
```

Then to get non admins like

```
User::admins(false)->find($id);
```